# Invalid expression term '[' using c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Can someone assist me what's wrong in my code. I'm try to convert JavaScript code to C# code

```
public class SplitString
{
  public static string[] Solutions(string str)
  {
    arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2){
      second = str[i+1] || '_';
      arr.push(str[i] + second);
    }
    return arr;
    
  }
}
```

And i encounter this error

> src/Solution.cs(5,11): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '['
> src/Solution.cs(5,12): error CS0443: Syntax error; value expected

Comment: You'll need to learn a bit about C# syntax I'm afraid. `arr = []` isn't valid C#, and `array.push` doesn't exist in C#, to pick on just two examples

Comment: Thanks for the response @canton7. and im trying to convert this list of codes to c#

can you help me please, I really need it. 

[link](https://www.bokki.org/codewars/6kyu/6kyu-split-strings/)

Comment: what it does `second = str[i+1] || '_';`?

Comment: @Noyti if you really need it, then you're going to have to understand what the original code *does*, and convert the *intent*, not the code directly

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular, please note that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service: you can't post a specification and expect other people to write code to meet it, for free. You *can* attempt to solve the problem yourself, and ask specific questions about the issues you encounter.

Comment: SO is no code translation service. To translate code and to be sure it does the correct thing you simply need to be able to write and read both c# and javascript. Right now it seems like you do not know c#. To remedy this start learning it, work through a couple of tutorial during the next weeks.

Comment: Do a quick read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/program-building-blocks. Just a quick scroll so you see the basic C# block and syntaxe.

Comment: please ***do not*** simply repost your question [when your first one, which is exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66471316/convert-javascritp-to-c-sharp) gets closed. if it's a bad question then, it will still be a bad question later on.

Answer (score 1):

javascript and C# are completely different languages; .NET / C# arrays are fixed size - so, you *might* want a list here:

```
var arr = new List<string>();
for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2){
  var second = str[i+1]; // || '_'; <== this on the right makes no sense in C#
  arr.Add(str[i] + second);
}
return arr.ToArray();
```

Comment: I encounter this error:

`src/Solution.cs(5,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Noyti You need to import `System.Collections.Generic` via `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file

Comment: @Noyti Anotehr example of something every C# programmer know. You need a full tutorial, not a [so] answer